# how to use Choco to set objective like 3.5X+4.2Y?

Tags: java, choco

I am new to Choco. I found an example online saying showing how to set the object as below

```
// Model objective function 3X + 4Y
IntVar OBJ = model.intVar("objective", 0, 999);
model.scalar(new IntVar[]{X,Y}, new int[]{3,4}, OBJ)).post();
// Specify objective
model.setObjective(Model.MAXIMIZE, OBJ);
```

What if my coeffs is double value? More specifically, if my objective function is 3.5X+4.2Y, how can I set the Objective? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: not the focus of your question, but Java naming conventions would say `IntVar obj` (instead of `IntVar OBJ`).

Comment: Constraint programming is int-focused. While choco might support floats (cant check now), i would still recommend to simply scale: 3.5x + 4.2 y becomes 35 x + 42 y. This is not uncommon.

Comment: Thanks @sascha. Please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.